# How to change default username/hostname for Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS LiveCD?

Tags: ubuntu, iso, livecd, initrd

I'm trying to edit the default username/hostname for a a custom Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS LiveCD.

I'm understanding I need to edit the `/etc/casper.conf` file that resides inside `$ISO_MEDIA/casper/initrd`, which I need to decompress first - where `$ISO_MEDIA` is the directory the original ISO contents were extracted into.

But in all the tutorials I've found, this file has an extension such as `.lz` or `.gz`, which is not my case.

I tried anyway following those tutorials, decompressing the file as instructed:

```
(cd $ISO_MEDIA/casper/tempinitrd && lzma -dc -S .lz $ISO_MEDIA/casper/initrd | cpio -imd --no-absolute-filenames)
```

However I get an error stating that the file has an invalid format:

```
lzma: /iso/custom/media/casper/initrd: File format not recognized
```

And when I run `file $ISO_MEDIA/casper/initrd` I have this output:

```
initrd: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

So I figured running only `cpio` only  would perhaps be enough, such as in:

```
(cd $ISO_MEDIA/casper/tempinitrd && cpio -imd --no-absolute-filenames < $ISO_MEDIA/casper/initrd)
```

It seemed to work, but now I have a file structure like the following: `kernel/x86/microcode/...` and `casper.conf` is nowhere to be found.

I feel like I'm walking in circles at this point. Any help figuring this out is appreciated.

Some of the tutorials I found were:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomizeLiveInitrd

Comment: I have a couple of answers that might help with your attempts to expand and rebuild the `initrd` image. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260675/why-cant-i-extract-all-of-the-ubuntu-20-04-live-server-amd64-iso-initrd . https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435396/load-drivers-to-initrd

Answer (score 1):

changing the default user seems like a daunting task since many setup variables depend on it for locality reasons.

it might be easier to append a setup script to root user to change the outcome of the first user that is made.

this is just my personal opinion of course.

a simple sh script to do so:

```bash
# make temp user
sudo adduser tempuser
# make permissions
sudo usermod -aG sudo tempuser
sudo adduser tempuser
#rename username
sudo usermod -l newusername -d /home/newusername -m oldusername
sudo groupmod -n newusername oldusername
# make a link to the directories
sudo ln -s /home/newusername /home/oldusername
# get chfn util
sudo chfn -f "firstname lastname" newusername
# delete temp
sudo userdel -r tempuser
```

Answer (score 1):

Maunt the USB device and search the grub.cfg `/USB/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg`, edit the following line:

> linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz

and add this boot option to the Linux kenel:

```
config live-config.username=anonymus live-config.user-fullname=anonymus live-config.hostname=anonymus
```

Should look something like this:

```
linux (loop)/live/vmlinuz config live-config.username=anonymus live-config.user-fullname=anonymus live-config.hostname=anonymus
```